# Book about a mathematical British captain

Tags: identification-request

I read an English-language novel around 2005 that chronicled the life of a fictional man from 1800's England—his childhood, work as a sailor, marriage, and promotion to captain. The cover shows part of a ship in water, and seemed to be written for young adults. Throughout the book, the man is especially methodical and skilled at navigation. In the last chapter, he's returning to London during an especially foggy night (perhaps Christmas Eve?). His wife and a friend are waiting for him, and the friend hopes he doesn't arrive that night because he assumes the main character would crash in such weather. But despite no visibility, the main character uses only a compass and his own calculations to safely navigate home and surprise the friend that night.

I've tried searching various combinations of "fiction", "British", "captain", "navigation", and "adolescent" with no luck.

Comment: One of the [*Horatio Hornblower*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatio_Hornblower) novels, perhaps?

Comment: That looks like a fascinating series, but unfortunately none of them look familiar.